# linking github to my server

Tags: git, github

Github tracks my changes and makes it easy for me to "upload" only files that I've worked on to the repository.

However then I have to upload them to my development server as well if I want to see them work.

Is there a way to have the git client push to my development server as well?

How do others handle this issue of efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a remote to your development server ( to the repo on the server):

```
git remote add devel url_to_repo
```

Once that is done, you can easily push to the development server:

```
git push devel master
```

If you are having a bare repo on devel ( as it ideally should be), you should write a post-receive script to checkout the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can just push to all remotes like this:

```
git remote | xargs -n 1 git push
```

This will go through all your remotes and push up your changes to each.

This assumes that you set up a remote for your development machine.