# Linking actual website to github

Tags: github

I have a site. I have local dev repo, an online github repo, and the live site (hosted by GoDaddy).

I want to do exactly what this person wants: [linking github to my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692985/linking-github-to-my-server)

Can I do the remote repo thing with Godaddy? Any hints? (I'm a beginner at git stuff)

Thanks

Comment: @Corbin I have GoDaddy Shared hosting. Would I do it through ssh? how else would i set up a remote repo (I need command line, right)?

Comment: Yes you need access to the command line (or a pre-setup thing, but godaddy does not offer that). I believe what you're wanting to do is not possible on GoDaddy shared hosting. Edit: Apparently they actually have ssh access available, so it might actually be possible.  Not sure on the details though :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide explains how to set up a remote and connect to a repo on your server: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

However, I *haven't* tried it.  I'm also a git beginner, and it terrified me a little, so I'm sticking with a manual FTP step, for now. Good luck!